# Литература по основам программирования

Tags: книги

Здравствуйте!

Уже долго программирую (2 года на разных языках) и чувствую некий провал в знаниях, при чтений профессиональной тех. литературе или при изучении документации. Я самоучка, и знания получал из разных источников. Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу на русском языке по основам программирования.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Полностью согласен с [[[[@andreycha](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha) (собственно, такой список и хотел написать).

От себя добавлю, если вы неуютно себя чувствуете в фундаментальных вопросах, то вот вам чтиво (формально этим вещам должны бы учить в университетах, но почему-то и там не всегда учат).

Алгоритмы и структуры данных:

- [Стивен Скиена. Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6290126/)
- [Томас Кормен. Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/)
- [Дональд Э. Кнут. Искусство программирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1335648/)

По базам данных и реляционной алгебре:

- [Гектор Гарсиа-Молина. Системы баз данных. Полный курс](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1351096/)
- [Стефан Фаро. Рефакторинг SQL-приложений](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4491539/)

И немного по ОСям (особенно если планируете плотно взаимодействовать с операционными системами, хотя и для общего развития полезно, чтобы понимать лучше понимать вопросы производительности, ввода-вывода, сетевого взаимодействия, работы с потоками):

- [Вильям Столлингс. Операционные системы](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1150703/)
- [Э. Таненбаум. Современные операционные системы](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6140231/)
- [Дж. Рихтер. Windows via C/C++. Программирование на языке Visual C++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4792123/)

Ну и совсем факультативно:

- [Ричард Стивенс. Протоколы TCP/IP. Практическое руководство](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1354276/)

ИМХО данная стопка книг (вместе со стопкой от [[[[@andreycha](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha)) при должном усердии и способности самостоятельно заниматься практикой может конкурировать с российским университетским образованием в среднем вузе.

Comment: Кингу дракона и K&R туда же.

Comment: [Книга дракона](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/146264/) вещь весьма специфическая (хотя это и про Кнута можно сказать). Но если уж браться за нее, тогда можно глянуть и [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html).

Comment: Первые 3 книги хороши, согласен, нужно знать в обязательном порядке. Остальные я бы советовал по направлению.

Comment: ИМХО Грубо говоря всё в программировании сводиться к битам ( системы счисления и все последствия ) и к алгоритмам обработки данных. А уже с помощью чего ты будешь кодить и в каком направлении без разницы, там нужны эти знания. Это и есть - база. Уже разного рода паттерны и чистоту кода, стоит изучать ( имменно изучать ), имея хороший опыт работы. В любом хорошем учебнике Вам расскажут как не надо писать и как надо. Либо доп литература на 100-200 страниц.

Comment: Спасибо. Такого ужас, как кернигана&ритчи читал. Пипец - она конечно емкостная, но очень сложная и скучная.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, Вы первый, от кого я слышу такое про K&R. 

Просто она **явно** не относится к учебникам по основам программирования. Это *легкое* описание нового (для своего времени) языка, видимо адресованное авторами профессионалам.

Естественно, в книге подразумевается, что читатель *хорошо знаком* с устройством компьютера (по крайней мере представляет что такое адресуемая память, регистры, стек, машинное представление данных и т.п.)

А вот что почитать про основы, как устройства компьютера, так и программирования, к сожалению, я Вам не смогу подсказать. Очень давно ничего такого не читал.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК полностью согласен с @avp, что K&R отношения к программированию вообще не имеет.

Comment: @Nofate поправьте пожалуйста линку, Гектор Гарсия-Молина на Кнута ведёт... За список спасибо!

Comment: @co11ter, FIXED

Comment: Минут 15 потратил на составление списка, а его нещадно выпилили.

Comment: А что вы ожидали. Таки варез же.

Comment: @igumnov, действительно обидно. 

Борьба с свободной информацией и доступностью знаний, однако...

Самое обидное, что я хотел скопировать куда-нибудь к сеье эти URL-ы, но не успел.

А (если он у Вас, конечно, сохранился) пришлите мне его по почте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @igumnov, значит не судьба, но ничего страшного.

Кстати, читаю я их обычно на e-ink, что для глаз, говорят, лучше (по личным ощущениям это правда). Жаль только, что в основном такие книги это pdf, а не html или fb2.

Comment: Преобразуйте ответ   igumnov  с литературой в ответ

Comment: @koza4ok, так список тот же, а ссылок уже нет.

Answer (score 14):

1. Учите английский язык.
2. О хорошем коде: "Совершенный код" Макконнелла, "Ремесло программиста" Гудлифа, "Рефакторинг" Фаулера, "Чистый код" Мартина
3. Об ОО-дизайне: "Паттерны проектирования" Гамма и др. или из серии Head First, "Приемы объектно-ориентированного программирования" Мартина
4. О профессионализме: "Идеальный программист" Мартина

Comment: @andreycha, книги, разумеется, замечательные, но это явно не основы)

Comment: Лучше прочитать эти книги, пусть не полностью понять с первого раза, спрашивая у старших товарищей пояснения, чем читать книги типа "ООП для чайников" или "Основы программирования" какого-нибудь лектора нашего ВУЗа. Тем более что человек уже 2 года программирует, какие-никакие знания но есть.

Comment: Ок,спасибо!
Уже понял, что английский нужен. Учу, но блин память на слова - просто ужас. Не знаю прям, что делать. Учу-учу, а потом бац и забуду :(.

Comment: SICP http://sicp.sergeykhenkin.com/about/.

Хотя тут и советуют книги недобитых китайских коммунистов. :)

Comment: Эти книги нужно читать уже ПОСЛЕ опыта работы, после того, как Вы сами начнёте ощущать программирование, учась на своих ошибках.

Answer (score 12):

Два года программирования это не *уже*, а *всего лишь*.

Я лично, лучше Кнута [Искусство программирования](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C8%F1%EA%F3%F1%F1%F2%E2%EE_%EF%F0%EE%E3%F0%E0%EC%EC%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%FF) ничего не видел. Книжка толстая, скучная для чтения, но стоит потраченных усилий. Это настоящий oldschool.

Основная ценность Кнута, в том, что она полностью абстрагирована от конкретного языка программирования и нацелена на собственно программирование. При этом изложение предельно академичное и сухое.

ИМХО, достаточно первого тома.

**Update**

Не к месту вспомнил, чье-то высказывание: программирование это искусство составления алгоритма с помощью 3-х операторов: цикла, условного перехода и безусловного перехода (`for, if, goto`).

P.S. Для адептов противников `goto` - будем считать что порядок следования инструкций это и есть `goto` перехода к следующей инструкции.

Comment: IMHO третий том тоже хорош. 

Но (опять же imho), TC Кнута не осилит.

Comment: > Но (опять же imho), TC Кнута не осилит.

Кнут он такой... трансцендентный ) Его можно бегло пролистать, потом вернуться, потом забросить, потом сесть читать по порядку , потом с конца....

Comment: Сегодня начну освоить всю эту литературу. Всем спасибо!

Comment: @Barmaley, Я считаю, что go to - это вредная привычка.  Мне один человек это аргументировал, сложно но убедительно.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, **всю** эту литературу осваивать, наверное, пока не стоит. Найдите что-нибудь под названием "Структурное программирование". Новой, наверное нет, а раньше их много было. 

Только отечественных авторов не стоит брать.

--

А по поводу goto, все не столь однозначно. Образно выражаясь - "всему свое место".

Comment: @ВладиславМСК "Безумству храбрых поём мы песню" (c) М.Горький

Comment: @alexlz, не понял Вас.

Comment: Это я о Вашем намерении "освоить всю эту литературу".

Comment: Вся жизнь программиста это бесконечный завуалированный goto. Вызов метода - goto к его началу. return - goto к оператору следующим за вызовом. Цикл - goto к началу его тела. if это два goto в две разных точки в зависимости от условия. Любая строка кода кончается неявным goto к следующей. Явное goto через идентификатор которое все считают плохой идеей и.т.д и.т.п.

Answer (score 5):

Вирт Н. "Алгоритмы и структуры данных".