# Литература по основам информатики

Tags: книги, информатика

Всем добрый день! Начал изучать PHP и немного C# (для себя ещё не выбрал на чём хочу остановится), вопрос в том что пообщавшись с более опытными людьми, я понял что зря начал учить сразу язык не разобравшись в основах. Как мне сказал один человек : "начни с чистого Си и разберись как работает железо и ОС и только тогда будет толк".

Поэтому посоветуйте с какой литературы начать этот путь, вы же тоже с чего-то начинали, я думаю это актуально и для меня. Спасибо вам!

Comment: Надеюсь, что найдётся другой человек, который скажет другие слова. С мнением этого "одного человека" я не согласен. Хотя, возможно, под "будет толк" мы понимаем разные ситуации.

Но вообще начинать с низкоуровневых вещей небезопасно. Потом к абстракциям труднее привыкать.

Comment: @alexlz, у Вас реально есть знакомые, которые начинали с чего-нибудь достаточно абстрактного (в крайнем случае Lisp), не окунались в низкоуровневые языки (хотя бы Java), как ОС работает не изучали, а потом хоть чего-то серьезное написали?

Comment: @avp нет. Но есть собственный опыт старта с ассемблеров.

Comment: @alexlz, ну, asm это другая крайность. 

Мне кажется (на самом деле у меня опыта в обучении нет), что начинать надо с pascal (но долго там не  задерживаться). 

Типы данных, примитивный ввод-вывод, основные структуры, управляющие операторы, функции и структура программ. Завершить написанием собственных "контейнеров" (списки, деревья, ...).

На этом **осознать** его ограниченность ("дубовость") и тогда уже пробовать другие языки, как "вниз" (C, asm), так и "вверх" (Java, python, js ...) и "вверх и в сторону" (lisp, awk, sql, ...).

Comment: @avp Паскаль -- неплохой язык для обучения (в 70х). Так же, как раньше был Basic. Сейчас лучше с ним (а Borland Pascal, который уже и delphi, и freepascal, это уже сильно не то) не связываться (с современными диалектами -- тем более. Столько намешано, что не только новичку сложно разобраться, откуда ноги растут). Лучшие языки для старта, вероятно, scheme и питон.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Литература по основам программирования](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/178607/%d0%9b%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 3):

Чарльз Петцольд "Код. Тайный язык информатики"

всё разжевано с самых основ.

Comment: Увидел фамилию, вспомнилось. Хотя и не по теме. 
Знаменитый Ч. Петцольд. Главный популяризатор программирования под винды... 8 лет назад статью написал http://www.charlespetzold.com/etc/doesvisualstudiorotthemind.html

Comment: ну в этой книжке про винды если и есть, то мало, она как раз полезна как основы информатики, не программирования даже.

Comment: eicto, хороший совет, сам когда-то читал эту книгу, правда не до конца. Хорошо подойдет новичку, совсем не знакомому с информатикой. Хотел её включить в свой ответ, но забыл и название, и автора.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо начинать с Герберта Шилдта (c, c++, c#), много книг и все очень доступно написаны

Comment: хреновый совет в общем-то

Comment: да, совет хренов. Герберт Шилдт, несомненно, профи, но он не умеет писать книги =)

P.S  Я не говорю про то, что он пишет непонятно, просто в его учебниках часто все дизориентированно.

Answer (score 0):

Читай SICP и K&R. Высокоуровневое программирование на Лиспе и функциональный подход будут очень хорошо контрастировать с процедурным С. SICP даст хороший кругозор, научит основным техникам абстрагирования - лучшая книга для начинающих. K&R хоть и является учебником по языку, но написана очень толково, в ней много важных вещей.