# Фундаментальные книги по программированию и алгоритмам

Tags: книги

Доброго времени. Есть опыт программирования на некоторых языках. Хотелось бы почитать что-то более абстрактное и фундаментальное. Посоветуйте пожалуйста литературу хорошую. Спасибо заранее

Comment: @Alexandr Crospov сто раз уже советовали - Кнут, Кормен, Вирт, Таненбаум

Comment: Опять двадцать пять... Смотрите [этот тред](http://hashcode.ru/questions/178607).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Литература по основам программирования](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/178607/%d0%9b%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Томас Кормен - Алгоритмы, построение и анализ

Дональд Кнут - Искусство программирования